# Are there events for when an Electron app is shown and hidden?

Tags: javascript, electron

I have been looking for Electron `app` events for when the **application** is shown or hidden. I see in the docs that there is ['browser-window-blur'](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-browser-window-blur) and ['browser-window-focus'](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-browser-window-focus) but those do not do what I want.

I would like to know when the user has switched to another application or switched back to my app. The above events get triggered if the user switches between browser windows – including the "developer's tools" window.

---

The code in `main.js`

```
app.on('browser-window-focus', () => {
    if (mainWindow) {
        console.log('browser-window-focus');

        mainWindow.webContents.send('projectMsg', { "event": "focus" });
    }
});

app.on('browser-window-blur', () => {
    console.log('browser-window-blur');
    if (mainWindow) {
        mainWindow.webContents.send('projectMsg', { "event": "blur" });
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know much about Electron, but if I'm not mistaken, many of the same methods used to detect this in a browser would work, like [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1060008)

Comment: there is no hide or or show event available to the entire app, but for any browser window object you have the hide and restore event listener.

Comment: Events you mentioned seem to be exactly what you need. What's wrong with them exactly? You want them to _exclude_ devtools, is that all?

Comment: @pergy - yes, I need them in exclude devtools.

Comment: @NoGrabbing I see. Unfortunately I cannot reproduce that case. For me these events don't fire for a devtool window, so they're working exactly as you want (in 2.0.2) If you could provide some real code that I can test, I'll give it a shot

Comment: @pergy – I added the code I am using. If I toggle between the main window and devtools, the events are triggered. Using Electron version 3.0.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me that it works exactly as you described, so maybe the requirements are different.

This code

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

app.on('browser-window-focus', (event, win) => {
  console.log('browser-window-focus', win.webContents.id)
})
app.on('browser-window-blur', (event, win) => {
  if (win.webContents.isDevToolsFocused()) {
    console.log('Ignore this case')
  } else {
    console.log('browser-window-blur', win.webContents.id)
  }
})
app.once('ready', () => {
  new BrowserWindow()
  new BrowserWindow().webContents.openDevTools({detach: true})
})
```

works the following way (in 3.0.3) given that nothing is focused initially:

- Clicking on window `1` prints `browser-window-focus 1`
- Clicking on window `2` prints `browser-window-blur 1 browser-window-focus 2`
- Clicking on devtools window prints <s>`browser-window-blur 2`</s> `Ignore this case`

So as far as I see devtool is not included in these events, windows are getting blurred for *any* other window focused (including devtool)

Comment: thanks for checking that out. I should have explained a bit further what the need is. I would like to do a reset of my app when it loses focus (clear screen, empty form fields, etc.) but I don't want to preclude being able to use the devtools. That is why I was looking for app-level show/hide events. If I act on the `blur` event then clicking on the devtools will clear the screen and so live content can't be examined. I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer: "No, there aren't app-level show/hide events.

Comment: Edited my answer to exclude that specific case. It doesn't work perfectly though. When you focus some other window _right after_ devtools you won't get event (by the nature of these handlers). However, that may be a feasible work around - if you always give back focus after using devtool

Answer (score 2):

There is also [show](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-show) and [hide](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-hide), though you have to explicitly show/hide the app with `win.show()` and `win.hide()` to trigger these events.

Answer (score 1):

Check out of these BrowserWindow's events:

[Event: 'blur'](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-blur): Emitted when the window loses focus.

[Event: 'show'](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-show): Emitted when the window is shown.

For example:

```
app.once('ready', () => {
  let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({show: false}) //Create main window
  mainWindow.on('show', () => {
    //Do something
  })
})
```

Hope this help.