# Electron how to check is application window showing?

Tags: electron

base on Electron api we use `win.show()` to show the hidden application windows.

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({show: false});
win.show();
```

But how can we detect is Electron application showing or hidden? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there events for when an Electron app is shown and hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52709372/are-there-events-for-when-an-electron-app-is-shown-and-hidden)

Comment: Yes it possibly useful, but not best match for what I need, I expect it has method like "win.isShowing()"

Answer (score 0):

`isVisible()` function can use

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winisvisible

```
browserWin.isVisible() // true or false
```